# Necessary with 2 neutral terminals on Light Sensor (Steinel Nightmatic 3000)?

Tags: electrical, neutral, motion-sensor

I am installing a Steinel Nightmatic 3000, which has the circuit diagram:

[image]

But since I have a 3 core cable to hand leading to my junction box I would like to install it in the following way:

[image]

[Junction box in blue]

Should this still work or is there a fundamental reason it won't? I am assuming there are two neutral terminals in the switch since each one can only fit a single cable and they are just making it easy to connect in the unit?

Comment: A 3-core cable would be line, neutral, and earth (ground in North America). Why do you think this justifies an alternate connection?

Comment: yes I see the confusion: from the junction box the 3 core carries live and neutral, and along the earth is the return L1 (correctly relabelled with tape). The earth terminal in the switch is surrounded by plastic so it does nothing, it effectively acts as a terminal ending, but I proposing re-purposing the earth cable.

Comment: What country is this?

Comment: You still haven't shown the circuit with both lamps and the switch or switches.

Comment: the switch is a light sensor switch (as depicted), there is no physical on/off switch. The circuit diagram is now complete except for earthing which connects both lamps to earth in the junction box to the earth cable from the mains.

Comment: Looks like the label is L' (that is L *prime*) not L1. This would mean that L' is just an alternate connection to line hot, so L' is not a "return" as you wrote in a comment above.  I assume that L and L' have zero voltage between them.

Comment: OK, apologies for that error, L' is controlled by the light sensor and activates when darkness sets it. It is not activated in daylight. But I understand the live terminals, the question is about the neutrals and whether the circuits are technically identical in my setup or there is a fundemental/electrical reason why I should use the installation circuit diagram

Comment: Is L' the hot which is switched by the photoelectric switch? Is the photoelectric switch part of this fixture? Is there also a manual wall switch? Do you want to connect from this fixture to another lamp fixture and have that second fixture also be under photoelectric control?

Comment: Moderator:  I am trying to get the OP to fully describe what he wants to do.

Comment: yes L' is the hot from photoelectric sensor which is built in to unit. no there are no other switches. there are two lamps as depicted in my proposed circuit diagram.

Comment: I may not be totally following you but first your sensor may need the load on the proper terminals to function properly. Second are you changing the wire function ie white= neutral,  black=hot, bare or green =ground? These are usually mandated by code and if needed you might need an additional wire to do what you want but I may not be following so left as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed connection appears electrically identical, but the screw connection is the approved one for this fixture. I don't see how you gain anything by doing it this alternate way.

What kind of connector would you be using to make the neutral connection? What is the power rating of the lamp?

EDIT

Connect a cable to the 2nd lamp at the connection block. Double up a switched hot in the port L' and put the neutral in the open neutral port.

EDIT'

If the ports in connection block will only accept one wire, then use the WAGO 221 connectors to tie into the hot and neutral to the present lamp.

Comment: All my connections are done using wagu 221 splicing connectors. two lamps connected in parallel each minimal wattage, say 40w each. I gain something because my output from switch needs to go back to junction box and I currently only have a 3 core cable not a 4 core (which of course I can get but just interested from theoretic point of view as well)

Comment: Are the two lamps in the same fixture or different fixtures? We would like to see the full circuit diagram. Are these two lamps independently switched, i.e., are there two switches?

Answer (score 1):

So I connected it up exactly as described in my circuit diagram and everything functions correctly, which implies that the 2 neutral terminals in the device are directly connected, and the second neutral attached to the lamp in the instructions circuit diagram is only needed for ease of use and utility reasons, it does not have to be used.

Answer (score 0):

### You're not allowed to repurpose the earth wire.

That is not permitted by Code anywhere in the world.

The existing wiring is wired as what we call a *switch loop* without neutral.

You are trying to convert to a "smart switch" which in fact requires neutral to power itself.

You do not have the wires in the wall necessary to support that.

You would need to add a second cable, or if device instructions allow, swap the existing cable for a 3-core *plus earth* cable.  Yes, I know this is a nightmare.

Since I suspect you are going to do this *anyway*, the least awful choice is to make the ground wire neutral.  But it's still pretty awful.

Comment: ok forget re-purposing the earth, suppose my cable had enough cores to do the job according to code, would my circuit diagram work equally well as compared to the installation instructions?( as for repurposing between the box and switch i think keeping brown for L, blue for neutral, and putting black tape on the green/yellow to label L' is the best)

Comment: OP:  Is the photocell switch part of the fixture or is the photocell switch separate and connected to the lamp by a cable? Is the 2nd lamp in an additional fixture to be connected to the first by a cable?

Comment: Harper, there is a neutral connected to the connection block and of course a neutral at the lamp. I can't see how this is a switchloop. Why can't he connect an additional cable connecting one wire to L' and one to the available N to go to an additional lamp in parallel.